# How to fix 'select option not selected ' in php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a select dropdown where i want to set selected option of select tag

I tried the following code

```
<select name="project" required class="form-control">
<option value="">Select  Project</option>
 <?php foreach ($this->getProject as $getproject):
                                                    ?>
 <option value="<?=$getproject['p_id'] ?>"<?php $getproject['p_id'] == $this->getdocs[0]['fk_project_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $this->getdocs[0]['fk_project_id']; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
```

Here 
`$getproject['p_id']=1 and $this->getdocs[0]['fk_project_id']=1` .But its not get selected

Comment: There is only one way to check both array value proper using print_r and var_dump. Maybe you can find out your issue.

Comment: your **option value="1"** is not dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace

```
<?php $getproject['p_id'] == $this->getdocs[0]['fk_project_id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>
```

with this code:

```
<?php echo ( ($getproject['p_id'] == $this->getdocs[0]['fk_project_id']) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>
```